# Confirmation for a picidea

Tags: species-identification, ornithology

I am sorting some pictures and found this one taken from Swiss Jura Mountains (North part, alt ~700m) in March 2013.

[image]

The day before I saw a `Dendrocopos major` (Great spotted woodpecker) and without looking thoroughly before I though it would be a young one.

Now when I examine in more details the picture it seems to be a `Dendrocopos medius` (Middle spotted woodpecker).

Am I right? Can someone confirm this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right, this must be a Middle spotted woodpecker *Dendrocopos medius*. It has clear stripes on its belly, and the black stripe on its cheek does not reach the beak. The beak is also  smaller, but size is always hard to judge.